# Force Chart Web Part to show all labels

Tags: web-part, chart-web-part

When using the Chart Web Part (horizontal bars) only every fifth bar-label gets displayed. The end user can't see what the other bars represent.

Is there a way to display every label for one axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And as soon as I said it, I found the right way.

Go to advanced properties, and set the interval for the x-axis to 1 and variable instead of fixed.

Imho the default interval should be 1 and the user should have the option to increase the labeling interval.

Comment: Brilliant, it really helped me and it works