# Data Labels in Chart webpart in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I need to display the Pie graph using Chart webpart. In the graph I need to display Name, Value and Percentage for each section. Please let me know how to achieve this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in "Data & Appearance" -> "Customize Your Chart" -> "Step 4: Chart Element Properties" -> Tab "Data Labels and Markers" select:
- Show Labels
- Show default values. 
Additionally, maybe you should look into this: 
[Force Chart Web Part to show all labels](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/66750/force-chart-web-part-to-show-all-labels) - The problem is quite similar to yours and there’s an answer.